# WCF Service Returns 400 error when using WebGet

Tags: c#, wcf

I don't know much about WCF. But I have a very basic service that I'm trying to execute. My service code looks like this:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false)]
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/IsValidRequest")]
    public bool IsValidRequest()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Like I said, a very basic service. When I enter "http://localhost:[port]/MyService.svc" into my browser, I see the service description page. However, "IsValidRequest" is not listed like I thought it would be (maybe this only happens with .asmx's). Either way, when I enter "http://localhost:[port]/MyService.svc/IsValidRequest" into my browser, nothing is returned. In Fiddler, I see that I get an HTTP 400 error. However, there is nothing that gives me any inkling as to what the problem could be.

Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What type of web service it is, seems to be a mix of SOAP & REST?

Comment: Maybe that's my problem. I want this to be a pure REST service. I thought that's how I had this setup. Regardless, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does your **web.config** look like?? The <system.serviceModel> section would be of great interest! Also: can you also post the contents of your `MyService.svc` file?'

Comment: I dont' have anything in system.servicemodel related to MyService. Should I have stuff there? MyService.svc just points to MyService.svc.cs which is provided above.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger to wp3 process to see if it's even getting to your service? Seems like a config error to me otherwise you'd get a 500 error.

Comment: My answer below assumes you're using .net 4.0 btw. Are you using 4.0 or 3.5?

Answer (score 4):

Use the following config (change the namespaces to match your code)

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="GetBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"  contract="WcfService1.MyService">

    </endpoint>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GetBehavior">

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />          
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Your .svc file should look like:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.MyService" CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

[image]

Comment: I had a few typos. The binding need to be webHttpBinding and your service name has to match your fully qualified class name that implements your service

Comment: this works for me using the service code the op provided http://localhost/service1.svc/IsValidRequest returns   <boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>

Comment: The OP has said he wants this to be a REST based service. Why are you suggesting he turn on metadata support in his service (serviceMetadataBehavior) - this is a SOAP feature

Comment: Just to make sure the service is working. It can be turned off with ease.

Comment: Indeed it can but it doesn't tell you anything about whether its working as a REST endpoint only as a SOAP endpoint and so on that basis could be misleading

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the WSDL for the message is irrelevant because as you have said in a response to a comment you want this to be a REST based service and WSDL is a SOAP construct. On that basis you should remove a `<serviceMetadata>` behavior if you have one as this is about SOAP metadata.

To diagnose problems like this you should turn on tracing in WCF (I have a short screencast [here](http://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/Screencasts.mvc/Watch?video=WCFTracing.wmv) that shows you how to do it). This should highlight what the problem is in processing the message

To wire up the REST plumbing without adding a section in the config for your service add the following to your config file under the system.serviceModel section

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: The problem is that he didnt have ANY configuration for his service. Not the metadata being turned on. You can't trace if you can't access it. Please read his question.

Comment: in .NET 4 he doesn't need any configuration related to the service to expose it as a REST service - either a protocol mapping for HTTP to map it to webHttpBinding and an endpoint behavior for webHttp or using WebServiceHostFactory in his .svc file to do the same

Comment: He says he was getting 400 errors which I also get when trying his code...until I add the configuration. It's still WCF even if it is REST. If you dont want to configure it then use MVC.

Comment: I'm not saying he didn't need to wire in the REST plumbing via configuration - I'm saying he didn't need to create a service element for it. He never said he had no system.serviceModel configuration just none explicitly for the service. Also, 400s can be caused by more than lack of REST plumbing (which wasn't necessarily the case from his description) so that's why I suggested using tracing to make certain