# WCF service with WebGet doesn't work

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service where everything is started programmatically (and need to continue doing so) and I want this service to respond to `[WebGet]` attributes.

However, when I call one of the WCF methods the service returns a 400 Bad Request.
This would initially seem like a duplicate of [WCF Service Returns 400 error when using WebGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588378/wcf-service-returns-400-error-when-using-webget) or [Bad Request 400 while accessing WCF Rest service (WebGet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725784/bad-request-400-while-accessing-wcf-rest-service-webget) but both of these solutions add to `web.config`, a file I don't have because I need to do everything programmatically.

I have tried to add a WebHttpBinding to what seems like the endpoint, but it doesn't work properly (I'm probably not doing it the correct way).

The code below starts without errors, but when I try to go to `http://localhost:8765/MyService/MyTest` I get the aforementioned `400 Bad Request`

What am I missing?

**WCF starter**

```
MyService myService = new MyService();
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(myService, new Uri("http://localhost:8765/MyService"));
ServiceBehaviorAttribute behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

foreach(ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints) {
    endpoint.Binding = new WebHttpBinding();
}

host.Open();
```

**Service interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string MyTest();
}
```

**Service implementation**

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    public string MyTest() {
        return "Response from WCF service";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code I wrote to initialize and start my WCF restful services completely from code:

```
public static WebServiceHost InitializeAndStartWebServiceHost(int port, string endPointName, object serviceModel, Type implementedContractType) {
        var baseAddress = new Uri($"http://0.0.0.0:{port}/{endPointName}");
        WebServiceHost host;
        try {
            host = new WebServiceHost(serviceModel, baseAddress);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Debug.Print("Error when creating WebServiceHost, message: " + exception.Message);
            return null;
        }

        // ReSharper disable once UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer
        var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

        //By default, TransferMode is Buffered which causes C# wcf client to be slow as hell (>500ms for requests which give >2kB responses).
        //I am not exactly sure why this helps, but it helps!
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(implementedContractType, binding, "");
        var behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
        behavior.HelpEnabled = false;
        behavior.DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare;
        // We will use json format for all our messages.
        behavior.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
        behavior.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
        behavior.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = false;
        behavior.FaultExceptionEnabled = true;


        host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(behavior);

        try {
            host.Open();
        } catch (AddressAccessDeniedException) {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Application must run with administrator rights.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        return host;
    }
```

Comment: I think the key to what I was missing was `WebServiceHost` and adding a new `WebHttpBinding` as a new endpoint (with a blank address) to the host. Doing those two things made it work.